# Is there a functional reason why the right side of the heart has a tricuspid valve while the left has a bicuspid one?

Tags: evolution, human-anatomy, heat

Is there a functional reason why the right side of the heart has a tricuspid valve while the left has a bicuspid one? Why is it necessary that the right atrioventricular valve be 3-cusped?

Comment: This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic (citing reliable sources), and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: The reason why I asked this here is because I failed to get ANY information online (& therefore I have no nothing else to show).

Comment: That's fine, but if you don't include answers the questions I asked in your post, then we have to take that on *faith* — if you aren't willing to make that effort and have little reputation here why should we believe you? Many questions get asked here where little (or no) effort has been made, or the effort has been misdirected — if you tell us what you've tried then someone may be able to help ...